# Counting Blank Cells in SUMIF Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have an excel sheet when I am trying to use `SUMIF` to add values based on the values of another range as below screenshot:

[image]

I am using the below `SUMIF` formula:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B560,"<=10000",A2:A560)
```

My target is to have the sum of cells in column A if their corresponding value in column B is less than or equal 10,000.
My issue is that excel ignores the blank cells while I need them to be counted as less than 10,000. I can't manually replace blank cells because it is a long sheet.

I appreciate your time and support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is an additional `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B560,"<=10000",A2:A560)+SUMIF(B2:B5260,"",A2:A560)
```

[image]

Another option is `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A560*(B2:B560<=10000))
```

[image]

A third option, if you have access to the `FILTER` function:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A2:A560,B2:B560<=10000))
```

[image]

Comment: One more question, is there a way that I can select a full column (A:A) but with excluding the first cell (A1)?

Comment: Just do `A2:A10000` or some suitable end cell that goes past the end of your data.

Comment: @user13472501: `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))*(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A))<=10000))`